# How to find svg element using selenium and retrieve the value of date/time in a published Facebook post?

Tags: facebook, selenium-webdriver, svg, tags, screen-scraping

As you know recently Facebook is using svg tag to load data and time of published posts.
I want to retrieve the value of some particular posts. The challenge is first do Hover and be wait till the content of date/time to be appeared, now how to get it from svg tag. Below the html code has been provided:
[image]

[image]

```
<span>
<span aria-labelledby=":rfq:" class="x1rg5ohu x6ikm8r x10wlt62 x16dsc37 xt0b8zv"><alfohmkfc-ngwhlbrgw><alfohmkfc-ngwhlbrgw><alfohmkfc-ngwhlbrgw><alfohmkfc-ngwhlbrgw>**<svg style="height: 16px; overflow: visible; width: 86.6855px;"><use xlink:href="#SvgT15" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"></use></svg>**</alfohmkfc-ngwhlbrgw></alfohmkfc-ngwhlbrgw></alfohmkfc-ngwhlbrgw></alfohmkfc-ngwhlbrgw></span></span>
```

Now how to use svg tag to get the content?

Answer (score -1):

To retrieve the value of date/time in a published Facebook post using Selenium with Python, you can follow these steps:

Hover over the element to make the date/time information visible.
Locate the SVG element that contains the date/time information.
Extract the text content from the SVG element.
Here's an example Python code using Selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Initialize the webdriver (you may need to adjust the path to your WebDriver)
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')

# Open the Facebook post URL
post_url = 'https://www.facebook.com/your_post_url'
driver.get(post_url)

# Find the element that needs to be hovered over
hover_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, 'your_xpath_to_hover_element')

# Hover over the element
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(hover_element).perform()

# Wait for the SVG element to be visible
svg_xpath = 'your_xpath_to_svg_element'
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
svg_element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, svg_xpath)))

# Extract the text content from the SVG element
date_time_text = svg_element.text

# Print the retrieved date/time
print(f"Date/Time of the post: {date_time_text}")

# Close the browser
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks for prompt answer. I tried on this approach already and the retrieved list is empty , I have updated the Question above related to html code. please guide me based on the provided code.